# Host timezone change does not reflect on docker container

Tags: docker, timezone, ubuntu-20.04

For a project, I need a container whose timezone is synced to host machine's timezone. My container should have the ability to sync to timezone changes on host machine at runtime. For this purpose I mounted /etc/localtime symlink and /etc/timezone file as per googling the topic.

My host machine is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Below is my docker run command:

```
docker run \
 -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
 -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro \
 --name openjdk-jdk11-slim \
 -it --rm \
 openjdk:11-jre-slim
```

After container starts, if I change the timezone of host machine via;

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Bissau
```

I see that date command inside container (container's interactive terminal) still outputs the timezone state of when container created. After changing timezone on host, if I recreate container, then only I can get the new timezone in container.

Is there an elegant way to fix this?

PS: My Docker version is as follows;

```
testuser@test-ubuntu:~$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
```

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/timezone-does-not-sync-from-host-to-container-at-runtime/122334

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set an environment variable in the Docker container? As an example,

```
docker run -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam debian:jessie date
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but maybe I did not make myself very clear, my issue is not setting the timezone of container to a specific one. I would like to see the timezone change at host machine reflected on container. I tried setting an environment variable via -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam though, result is no luck. When I changed the timezone of host machine, container timezone was still Europe/Amsterdam at this very trial.

Comment: @lupus I see. Thank you for your clarification. So, if you're using Windows, you can create a file named timezone and add it to the volume list like this:
`docker run -v c:/<your_path>/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro ...`

Comment: Actually as stated in the original question, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as host machine. Again, as stated in the original question, I already did the mounts said to be the fix to this issue on Google, result is no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the TZ via cat so it's automatic:

```
if [ -f "/etc/timezone" ]; then
    temp_tz="$(cat /etc/timezone)"
    if [ ! -z "$temp_tz" ]; then
            export TZ=$temp_tz
    fi
fi
```